# What does f.input in a rails form do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I started to program with Rails after i finished some lessons in Ruby.
When i looked at someone's code I got confused.
It looked like he makes some form using Rails but I just can't understand how it works.
Well just take a look on the code... Hopefully you can help me to understand this:

```
=f.inputs do
   =f.input :type, :as => :transmission, :label => false
   =create_submit_link('Do something',:id=>'transmit')
```

Now the f.input row will print me 3 rows of following stuff:
(row 1): radio_button | labeltext | text_field; (row 2): 1x radio_button |labeltext| number_field; (row 3): radio_button |labeltext|

How is that possible? :O

Comment: It comes from [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) gem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`f.inputs` is not defined in rails. You may be using "simple-form" gem. [Simple Form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) has various views helpers to generates html contents. It has various method such as: `text`, `radio`, `email` however `:as => :transmission` options seems to be user defined as its not defined in "simple form" also. You can take look at https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/form_helper.rb. `f.input` work same as `f.textbox` or similar to rails but it has much more options than bare rails html helpers.

Comment: Note: `SimpleForm` it is just wrappers around default `form_for` and `fields_for` helpers in `Rails`.

Comment: Yes, it is just wrappers around form_for and fields_for help